# Unable to push a new file in git because of error: "Everything up-to-date"

Tags: git, bitbucket

Using Bitbucket I am trying to take a file on my local repository and push it to a remote repository.

I cd into my local repo in cmd:

```
cd C:\Users\my_name\my_repo\folder
```

I then run `git status` and get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I then add my file via:

```
git add C:/Users/my_name/my_repo/my_notebook.ipynb
```

and this runs without any output.

I then commit via:

```
git commit -m "Updates made to my_notebook"
```

And I get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

This looks strange. I then try to push via `git push` and get:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

This does not look promising. And then I got to bitbucket and see that the new change was not made.

What might I be doing wrong with pushing this local file to my remote bitbucket repository? I am confused why I am being told there is nothing to commit, when I do indeed have a file I would like to commit.

EDIT:

Contents of corresponding `.gitignore` file:

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db


# python files #
######################
*.project
*.prefs
*.pydevproject
*.pyc
*.pyo

# latex files #
######################
*.dvi
*.pdf
*.aux

# other random files #
######################
construct*
Construct*
~*
Archive *
*.egg-info/
*.idea
.ipynb_checkpoints
*checkpoint.ipynb
output
```

Comment: There are several typos in your examples here, so I can only assume you're making similar typos in your actual situation. (`my_name` vs `myname` for example)  Also, similarly, you say the repo is in `folder`, but you are adding that `.ipynb` outside that folder.

Comment: The output from the commit -m is telling me nothing happened.

Comment: @Alex what would the push be then, `git push origin`? And how would that work if after commiting I was told there is nothing to commit?

Comment: You might be in the wrong directory, judging by the first part of your question. Try going up a directory to the root of your repo…and then repeat the steps.

Comment: @Alex good suggestion, but that was largely just an example to avoid writing out the whole filepath. I think the issue might be more aligned with why I am getting an error that there is nothing to commit.

Answer (score 1):

## .gitignore

Is there a `.gitignore` file? If so, check whether it is ignoring the file you'd like to add.

If there is one, you'll find it here:

```
project/
  .git/
  .gitignore
```

Here's an example of the contents of a `.gitignore` file:

```
/.idea/
cache/
*.swp
```

This would ignore the `project/.idea/` directory, as well as any `project/*/cache/` directories, and any files with the `.swp` suffix.

**NOTE:** Your particular `.gitignore` file is configured to ignore`.ipynb_checkpoints` files, and any file that ends with `checkpoint.ipynb`.

The maintainer of the repository added those lines to prevent certain types of files from being added to the repository. For example, things like `.Spotlight-V100` wouldn't be helpful to others, so they are ignored. The maintainer didn't want ipynb files in the repository, so you should follow their wishes and exclude them! If you feel that's a mistake, and they *should* be included, then you should talk to the maintainer. When those ipynb lines are removed from the `.gitignore` file, then you'll be able to add them just fine--as you would in any other project.

Comment: Where would I find this .gitignore file?

Comment: If there is one, it will be right next to the `.git` directory.

Comment: Yes I do see a .gitignore file access when I did the last git actions, but I am not sure how to read or interpret the contents of this file.

Comment: Can you post the contents here?

Comment: You should be able to open it in a text editor, or through "nano .gitignore" on the command line.

Comment: I just updated my post with the contents of the `.gitignore` file

Comment: That .gitignore file is set to ignore any file that ends with "checkpoint.ipynb"

Comment: Ok, what do I do about this? I have never ever encountered this issue with updating notebooks with git before today.

Comment: You could try removing the lines: .ipynb_checkpoints and *checkpoint.ipynb

Comment: Note that, once you've added a file, .gitignore *will not* retroactively ignore it.

Comment: The maintainer of the repository added that section to prevent certain types of files from being committed to the repository.  For example, things like `.Spotlight-V100` wouldn't be helpful to others, so they are ignored. The maintainer didn't want *.ipynb files in the repository, so you should follow his wishes and exclude them. If you feel that's a mistake, and they SHOULD be included, then you should talk to the maintainer. When those *.ipynb lines are removed from the .gitignore file, then you'll be able to commit them just fine.

Comment: This is not true, gitignore does not block adding a file manually to the staging area and including it in the next commit.

Comment: You can add a file to the staging area manually, but if the file matches a rule in the .gitignore file, then it will be ignored when you to try to add the file to a later commit. If you disagree with that, could you clarify?

Comment: @Andy I don't "disagree"; this isn't a matter of opinion. It's a matter of fact. `.gitignore` affects `git add` (and `git status`). It has no effect upon `git commit`. That's the way it is. Try it for yourself. Consult the documentation. Whatever. See also Jim Redmond's comment: once you've _added_ a file (to the staging area / index), `.gitignore` will not retroactively ignore it.

Comment: When I said, "if the file matches a rule in the .gitignore file, then it will be ignored when you to try to add the file [...]" I was trying to communicate that the `.gitignore` file would have an effect on the `git add` command--same as you.  I never believed that `.gitignore` file would have an effect on `git commit`, only that `git add` comes before `git commit`--which is how the confusion started. That's why I wanted you to clarify: I knew that there must have been a miscommunication, and I wanted us to understand each other.

Comment: I can see that the wording in the answer is confusing. I'll edit it.

Comment: My comment responds to your "You can add a file to the staging area manually, but if the file matches a rule in the .gitignore file, then it will be ignored when you to try to add the file to a later commit." That's still there and still false.